# An exception occuring while creating summary task and task information in Microsoft Project via Add-In using VSTO

Tags: c#, vsto, office-addins, ms-project, comaddin

In my VSTO(Visual Studio Tools for Office) Add-in for Microsoft Project, I'm getting this error:

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'The argument value is not valid.'

I am trying to Add the Summary Tasks, and Tasks Information. The exception occurs in this block of code.

```
 countryNameSummaryTask.OutlineChildren.Add(regionNameSummaryTask);
```

Here is my code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
{
Project project = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveProject;

// Create Country Name Summary task
string countryName="US";
Task countryNameSummaryTask = project.Tasks.Add(countryName);
countryNameSummaryTask.OutlineLevel = 1;

// Create State/Region Name Summary task
string regionName="TN";
Task regionNameSummaryTask = project.Tasks.Add(regionName);
regionNameSummaryTask.OutlineLevel = 2;
countryNameSummaryTask.OutlineChildren.Add (regionNameSummaryTask);

// Adding list of tasks
var phases = new List<Phase>(){
new Phases() { Name="P11", Start=DateTime.Now, Finish=DateTime.Now.AddDays(2)},
new Phases() { Name = "P22",Start=DateTime.Now, Finish=DateTime.Now.AddDays(2) },
new Phases() { Name = "P33", Start=DateTime.Now, Finish=DateTime.Now.AddDays(2) },
new Phases() { Name = "P44", Start=DateTime.Now, Finish=DateTime.Now.AddDays(2) }, 
}

foreach (var phase in phases)
{
 Task newPhaseTask = project.Tasks.Add(phase.Name);
 newPhaseTask.OutlineLevel = 3;
 regionNameSummaryTask.OutlineChildren.Add(newPhaseTask);
}

}
```

Comment: Do you have a Task Collection?  Read text at top of following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.task  Once you have a Task Collection than you can use OutlineChildren.

Comment: Yes, I think this line `Task countryNameSummaryTask = project.Tasks.Add(countryName);`  is member of Task Collection. But still exception occurring at line `countryNameSummaryTask.OutlineChildren.Add(regionNameSummaryTask);`

Comment: Add does not have a return value.  The return value is void.

Comment: There is no Add method of OutlineChildren. It is a read-only collection of tasks.

Comment: Also, it is unnecessary in this case since you are setting the outline level to one lower than the previous task, automatically making the country task a summary task and the region task a child task.

Comment: Actually I want country task as Parent task, region task as child task, phase tasks are the subtasks.

Comment: Parent is another word for Summary, so just delete the OutlineChildren.Add lines and you should be fine.